# Unresolved external symbol in library in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, development-environment, lib

I am trying to compile un software which is written in C++ at visual studio 2017,but I face un problem in the library. The description is like this.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall CEZOptionsDlg::AddButton(class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > >,unsigned int)" (?AddButton@CEZOptionsDlg@@UAEXV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@I@Z)
```

I have already included the path of library in the "VC++ directories" and added the *.lib in "Additional library directories". 
The setting is in the mode "Debug" , "x86".

I have tried to change the setting in "Runtime library" but it doesn't work. 
I have tried to change the "calling convention", but it doesn't work ,too.

Because it is a software who is written a bit long ago, I doubt that is it possible that the problem is on the x86 and x32. But in the "configuration manager", it runs at platform win32. It shouldn't be wrong.

I also doubt it might be the problem in the .dll, but I just compile the software. It should only be related to .lib

I don't know if the *.lib is complete because I don't have source code of this library.

I have been trapped in the problem for 2 days. Can anyone come and help me.

Comment: Libraries (lib files) can be x86 and x64 you might also want to check which you're linking against.

Comment: In "Additional library *directories*" you should only add *directories*, not the libraries themselves. Those have their own place in the project settings.

Comment: there is only one libraries file, but i don't know if it is in x86 or x64. How can i  know?

Comment: In fact, in the "Additional library directories", i do add the path, not the libraries. I have also tried to add the libraries files in the Input->additional Dependencies, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: User old version of VS and check.

Comment: C++ DLLs, compiled with different versions of VS, probably do not work well together. -> [Mixing Multiple Visual Studio Versions in a Program is Evil](http://siomsystems.com/mixing-visual-studio-versions/)

Comment: I have tried to use old version of VS. It doesn't work, too

Comment: *because I don't have source code of this library.* -- Is it [this library](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/809/WebControls/)?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out it is caused by a very old version of de Visuel C++(VS 98), who is probably the same age as I am. After I used the VS98 in Visuel Stdio 2017( which sound ridiculous ), the code can build correctly.
I think this problem may only be occured to me. But, anyway, I hope this solution will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Your checklist

1) Confirm toolkit V110, v120,v14,v141

2) Confirm x86 or x64

3) Confirm MT ( static -> need only lib) or ML ( dynamic -> need a dll & lib)

4) DLL may be release or debug version

5) VS SDK version  ( SDK 7.xx , SDK 8.1, SDK 10.xxx etc)

Use dumpbin.exe from your VS 2017 to find details for the exported methods and other signatures from the lib file. Use dependency-walker ( free download on net) to analyze the DLL file.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I use the toolkit v141 with SDK 10.xx. I try to change it to v141_xp
I have changed the SDK 10.xx to 8.1, 
I have tried to change the copiler mode Debug to Release,

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I use the toolkit v141 with SDK 10.xx. I try to change it to v141_xp
I have changed the SDK 10.xx to 8.1, 
I have tried to change the compiler mode "Debug" to "Release",
I have tired to change the "use of MFC" to use "MFC in static library"
I haved changed all options in "configuration manager" from Win64 to win 32
but all these changes only showed the same error I mentioned above
I have used the dependency-walker to check my *dll.It says "can't find the file", i wonder if the problem is from the .dll?
I have tried the dumpbin.exe,I try figure how to use it

Comment: @QifengRUAN: dumpbin tell a lot from the header from the lib file. To analyzer lib file better you can also export the sumbols to a file and check later . Similarly for headers. Initially its a pain but you will learn better from the pain.  Like this: dumpbin YOUR.lib /symbols > symbols.txt